# How to setup Flash Player security settings through Android Application

Tags: android, cordova, flash, externalinterface

I have build an Android Application using PhoneGap.

The PhoneGap application loads a flash swf which call externalInterface functions and also has various external-interface functions exposed.

I am unable to make use of them when the application is running which is breaking down my application completely.

I did a bit of research on this, but could not found a positive reply.

Can any one help me with a code or process on how to enable Flash Player Global Security settings?

I forgot add my flash movie is built using ActionScript 2 and I can not port it to AS3.